# How to link index.html to css file for github page

Tags: html, css, github, directory, github-pages

I'm hosting a github page and want to link index.html to main.css, which is in a folder called "stylesheets" also in the root directory.

my file structure:

```
index.html
stylesheets
   - main.css
```

right now I have:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" />
```

in the `<head>`, but this doesn't work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you should create **gh-pages** branch that special branch of GitHub.
You can find and create it in setting page of you project by the button **Automatic page generator**.
The branch will map to the doamin http://username.github.io/project/

So the path should be `stylesheets/main.css` not `/stylesheets/main.css`

Comment: this is just a user site, not a project site

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the front '/' from `/stylesheet`, so that it loads up relative to the current route: `stylesheet/...`

Comment: This was actually the first answer, and it's correct. A little short on details, but correct.

Answer (score 1):

if it not project pages.. "mean" you are Creating a repo youruser.github.io 
(index of username.github.io) 
not atuo genereate gh-pages because its use template

its simply by doing:

1. clone it
2. create & move to branch gh-pages
3. commit & push it

   `/style` -> you are on root directory
   `style/`  -> you are on currrent directory
   `./style` -->  more safe to navigate current directory

wait 5 minutes ... and cheers!

Comment: +1 for the "_wait 5 minutes_". The changes are not reflected immediately in the site youruser.github.io/yourproject