# What path do I need to write to get css to work in GitHub pages?

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I have tried multiple file paths in my HTML head to get the CSS to load in GitHub pages but it won't. It loads locally but not on pages.

I tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/components/style.css">
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/components/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/components/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/components/style.css">
```

None work, any help would be amazing

[my repo](https://github.com/LHB410/portfolio)
[page](https://lhb410.github.io/portfolio/)

I tried changing the file name multiple times expecting the gh pages css to load it did not

Comment: Try `./` at the start?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to link index.html to css file for github page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23040619/how-to-link-index-html-to-css-file-for-github-page)

Comment: Tried and tested still not working :( thanks though

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25376201/14881263). Check out this stack overflow answer, which worked for me.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link but I have already tried this solution...any other suggestions welcome